# Precise lose happens when double minus int

Tags: c++

```
    float_part = abs(double_n) - (int)abs((double_n)); //The target number is 28187281.525
    cout << float_part; // The result is 0.525
    cout << ((abs(double_n) - (int)abs((double_n))) == 0.525) ; //The result is 0
```

And in the following calculation, the results will be wrong after some more calculation based on this result, which seems because of precise lose.

However, if I change

```
       float_part = abs(double_n) - (int)abs((double_n));
```

to

```
       float_part = 0.525;
```

The result of following calculation will be correct. So this two "0.525" seem actually different.

Anyone knows what really happens?

I know IEEE 754, but if so why the cout results are same, both "0.525" not something like "0.524999999999"?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just because `std::cout` prints the same thing, doesn't mean it's exactly the same value. Try using [`std::setprecision`](http://ideone.com/m0FSY9) with different values. You'd be surprised.

Different precision will cause `std::cout` to round differently the value it outputs.

What you *should* do instead of comparing directly, is compare the distance between your result and the expected value. Something like:

```
const double epsilon = 1e-6;
//...
cout << abs(float_part - 0.525) < epsilon << '\n';
```

Comment: WOW! I just tested you are right. I didn't know cout will round value in this strange way. It seems, as long as calculation involves float or double, the result is not guaranteed to be something as expected...

Comment: @彭浩翔 -- "result is not guaranteed to be something as expected": that depends on what you expect. Most people's intuition fails them when floating-point math is involved. Real numbers have unlimited precision, and most people initially expect floating-point numbers to behave just like them. But floating-point numbers have limited precision, and **cannot** act just like real numbers. But consider: `int i = 1; i /= 3; i *= 3;` and `float f = 3; f /= 3; f *= 3;`. Nobody has a problem with the first one producing 0, but many people are surprised that the second one does not produce 1.

Comment: It seems when calculation involves float for many times, the result will gradually lose control, I mean even the 0.2*2 will result in 0.799999999..

Comment: @彭浩翔 You should read [this document](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#674). It's hardly comprehensive, but it's a good start to demystify floating point arithmetic.